# Batch rename folders appending fixed text and moving part of the name

Tags: directory, rename, pattern-matching, batch-jobs

I have several directories named in the pattern `[year] name`, like `[1900] aaaa`, `[1901] bbbb`, `[1902] cccc`, and so on. I'd like to append a fixed `text -`  to the beginning of the name and move the `[year]` part to the end, resulting in folders named as `text - name [year]` (or `text - aaaa [1900]`, as an example.

I'm trying rename from util-linux 2.36.2 `rename -nv '[' 'text - ' '['?` but I'm receiving `no matches found: [?`.

How can I do that right?

EDIT: in my original post, I forgot to mention all folders have a different name.

Comment: Had to make a couple edits but the answer I just posted now should work for you.  Make sure you read the information about my test files naming pattern.

Comment: What OS and rename implementation are you using (`rename --version`)? Can we assume you meant `mkdir '['{1900..1905}'] name'` or `mkdir '['{1900..1905}'] 'name` ?

Comment: @steeldriver You were right, my mistake. Your second option is the right syntax. I'll edit, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Perl `rename` tool (this is different from `rename` from the util-linux package):

```
rename 's/^(\[\d{4}\])( .*)/text -$2 $1/' *
```

---

Using `bash` and [parameter substring expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for i in \[[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\]\ *; do
  mv "$i" "text -${i:6} ${i:0:6}"
done
```

Comment: I preferred the bash approach as I'd not want to install anything else I'll probably use just a few times. It worked like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the year is the hard part here but this should work for you make sure you test it out first I tried it on a couple examples.

```
for n in *; do year=$(echo "$n" | grep -oz [[:digit:]]); mv "$n" "addon - text [$year]"; done
```

My test files where named "[year] text"  If your files are named differently then this will need to be adjusted slightly.

Jason C.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention an important piece of information: all directories are named differently. Like: [1900] aaa; [1901] bbb; and so on. Thus, the approach suggested by @Freddy works better in this situation. I'll edit my original post. Thanks again!

Comment: This should still work as long as it’s “[year] text” example “[2021] text” the “digit” in the grep command is the actual word digit it will match any  number then save it in variable year rename the file then add variable to the end of it either way should work just wanted to clarify encase anyone reads this in the future have a great day.

Comment: Ah after thinking about it I see what you mean well thanks glad you got it figured out have a great day.